# Android google maps custom tiles

Tags: android, maps, overlay, tiles

I'd like to build an app using google maps and I'd love to have some kind of custom tiles.
As I've found nothing on the web, I'd like to know if there is any way to do that on Android?

I found that library on open street map: http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/
But I'd prefer using google maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no support for custom tile sets with the Google Maps SDK Add-on for Android, sorry.

**UPDATE**

Maps V2 -- introduced well over a year after this question was asked and this answer was posted -- offers a `TileProvider` facility that apparently handles this.

Answer (score 2):

Just create your own `TileOverlay` and `TileProvider` to return tiles to the Maps API.  Then call `gmap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE)` to disable Google's tiles.